# CS50 Caesar segmentation fault explanation

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, cs50, argv

I can compile this code with no issues, the idea right now is just to test that I can successfully enter the cipher key(command line argument) without any issues before moving on. I was having no luck with finding out why my code would always return a segmentation fault, then I saw a tip to put a '*' before argv[1] in the 4th line, and that seems to solve all my issues. Can someone please explain to me why this is?

```
int main(int argc, string argv[]) // command line argument for the cipher key
{
    int key;
    if (argc == 2 && isdigit(*argv[1])) //the line in question
    {
        key = atoi(argv[1]); // convert the digit string into an integer
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Usage:./caeser key\n");
        return 1;
    }
printf ("%i\n",key);
}
```

Comment: You sure that `argv` is `string`and not `char *`? This is `C` not `C++`, right?

Comment: @eldesgraciado the question is tagged with `CS50`. There is a `string` type defined which is `char*`.

Comment: @eldesgraciado This question is just another example of how CS50's `string` abomination has confused ***another*** new programmer.  Using `char *` type to refer to an array of `char` values that is terminated by a `'\0'` value is a fundamental concept in C that CS50 obfuscates with their misguided "string" `typedef`.  It's like trying to teach someone to spell and then saying, "No, you really don't need to know what things called "letters" are."  Or "Numbers?  You don't need to know numbers to count!"

Comment: @AndrewHenle A `typedef`, huh? wow, that is absolutely _aberrant_. How can they teach using these practices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> then I saw a tip to put a '*' before argv[1] in the 4th line, and that seems to solve all my issues. Can someone please explain to me why this is?

This means, before you saw that tip, it looked like this:

```
isdigit(argv[1])
```

You are mixing types here.

`argv` is an array of `char*`. This means, `argv[1]` is of type `char*`.
But `isdigit` is expecting an argument of type `int`. You should get some compiler warning for that.
The function expects to get a value that is in range of `char` or `EOF`. Passing a pointer is very likely to provide some value way out of range.

If you add the `*` you dereference your char pointer and take the first character of that string. That is what is expected by `isdigit` and it works as it should.